# Visualization of a multivariate function

Tags: data-visualization, computational-statistics

This is somewhat vague, but suppose you have a black box function $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k)$, for which you have code, and you are interested in the behaviour of $f$ when the $x_i$ are i.i.d. standard Gaussian random variables. What are some good ways to visualize this function? To make it easier, we may assume that $k$ is smallish, say less than 10.

One particular relationship of interest is how $f$ varies with one of the input, say $x_i$. An easy way to visualize this relationship would be to sample the function for fixed values of $x_i$ while varying the other input (either in a structured way, or randomly, say), then box-plotting, which could show how the mean trend is affected by $x_i$, but also whether the scatter is affected (i.e. heteroskedasticity). However, interaction between $x_i$ and the levels of the other input might be masked by this approach.

What I am looking for is somewhat open-ended. I do not have a particular hypothesis that I am testing, but rather am looking for new ways of visualizing the response which might reveal peculiarities of the function.

Comment: p.s. maybe this should be a community wiki? I'm not sure how that works...

Comment: if you don't give us more info on $f$ and on what type of characteristic then it seems to be community wiki but I am not sure neither :)

Comment: The fact that $f$ in undefined makes it a feed of a different multivariate visualization methods, so it should be CW. And now it is.

Comment: it's fairly easy for me to fit $f$ to linear model, so we should assume that has already been done, and we are looking at the _residual_ from that fit. As I mentioned in the question, I am looking for interesting facts about the function, so I don't yet know what I might find. Because of this open-ended nature, I thought maybe it should be a CW. I am still not sure on how one decides whether a Q should be CW.

Comment: At first blush this question seems purely mathematical: visualizing the function has nothing to do with the distribution of its arguments.  However, the reference to "heteroskedasticity" suggests you're really trying to visualize an object that is more explicitly represented as $f(x_1, ..., x_k) + \epsilon$ or more generally as  $g(f(x_1, ..., x_k), \epsilon)$ where $epsilon$ is a zero-mean random variable and $g(z,0) = z$ for all z.  Isn't this just a response-surface analysis?

Comment: @whuber I don't know enough RSM to say for sure (and the wikipedia page is not helping me). I am not necessarily trying to optimize the function (gasp), but am trying to find interesting facts about it. What makes this a statistical question is that I'm not terribly interested in the case where any of the $x_i$ are far from zero (assumed standard normal), and so what constitutes 'interesting' should somehow be weighted by relevance.

Comment: @Shabbychef: Right, your stipulation of standard normals establishes you want to know $f$ in a neighborhood of the origin that doesn't extend more than a few units away. RSM occurs to me because it includes methods that *efficiently* explore the behavior of a function, so if evaluating $f$ is expensive, RSM methods may be helpful. If evaluating it is not expensive, you have a purely mathematical problem. If each evaluation for a given set of arguments can produce a variety of results, you need the $\epsilon$ term--but maybe you can eliminate it by averaging multiple evaluations at each point?

Comment: @whuber: as these things go, eventually $k$ will be sufficiently large, and the code will be sufficiently encumbered with bells and whistles that some sampling technique will have to be employed. I am not there yet, though.

Comment: @Shabbychef: That points away from answers proffered by eng-carlin (because dimensionality reduction won't accomplish anything) and Josh Hermann (because a tornado chart looks purely at one coordinate at a time and further reduces the graph of $f$ from one dimension to zero) and favors answers akin to Jeromy Anglim's.  Along those lines, Mathematica offers great utilities to interpolate and visualize functions, given either as formulas or as sampled data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you are at the initial, exploratory stages of the analysis I would start simple. Consider sampling your inputs using a [Latin Hypercube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_hypercube_sampling) strategy. Then, a tornado chart can be used to get a quick assessment of the multiple,one-way sensitivities f() has to the various input variables. Here is an example chart (from [here](http://www.add-ins.com/sensitivity_chart_creator.htm))

[image]

This chart is not that interesting, but an interpretation would be "NPV is most sensitive to Shipments, all other things being equal. But, the sensitivity is mostly on the upside, which is good. The Escalation variable induces sensitivity into NPV, but what looks to be skewed negatively a bit...".

You could do something similar for Mean(f) on the X-axis as well as Var(f)

Given what you find from some first glance visualizations like this, you could then slice and dice more and focus on specific variables or relationships between variables. Maybe you can revisit this thread in coming months and post the visualizations you found useful :)

Answer (score 3):

Just a thought, although I've never tried it.

- you could obtain a large number of values from the function across different parameter values
- take a tour of the resulting data in [ggobi](http://www.ggobi.org/) (check out [Mat Kelcey's video](http://vimeo.com/12292239))

Comment: ggobi looks interesting, but I am repelled by the `xml` data format. maybe I'll get over that, but it is not high priority.

Comment: @shabbychef Then check out the interface from R called rggobi http://www.ggobi.org/rggobi/

Comment: Bump for rggobi. I just downloaded it after reading @shabbychef's comment and it changed/rocked my world.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply some sort of dimensionality reduction technique like principal components and plot the value of the function as you vary the first, second, third etc. principal components, holding all others fixed.  This would show you how the function varies in the directions of the maximal variance of the inputs.

Comment: The inputs are assumed to be iid Gaussian, implying there is no direction of maximal variance.  But perhaps I have misinterpreted this assumption?